# if/if any in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list

What is the difference between if / if any in a list comprehension?

The code:

```
return [word for word in words if any(set(word.upper()) <= set(row) for row in ('QWERTYUIOP', 'ASDFGHJKL', 'ZXCVBNM'))]
```

gives me the expected result. However, if I use "if" instead of "if any", then the result is wrong.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) are not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(set(word.upper()) <= set(row) for row in ('QWERTYUIOP', 'ASDFGHJKL', 'ZXCVBNM'))` is a generator expression. `if` will always see this as a `True` value

`any` is a function. It iterates over the generator expression and returns a bool

There is no "if any" it's "if [some expression]" the `any` is part of the expression

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. The `any` method will return `True` the moment it meets the condition you are looking for as it iterates over the collection. In other words it 'short circuits' once it meets your condition.

So, inside your `any` you are determining this `True` condition. Once you move outside of it, the `if` in the overall comprehension is simply checking for whether the `any` did in fact return `True`. In the event it is `True` (aka the `if` passed the `True` check), you take the `word` in to the list you are crafting.